# Remove all the characters after $ sign using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all the characters that appear after "$" sign in my string using javascript.

Is there any function in javascript which can help me achieve this. I am quite new to client side scripting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there are a few different ways

```
var myStr = "asdasrasdasd$hdghdfgsdfgf";
myStr = myStr.split("$")[0];
```

Or

```
var myStr = "asdasrasdasd$hdghdfgsdfgf";
myStr = myStr.substring(0, myStr.indexOf("$") - 1);
```

Answer (score 15):

How about this

```
astr.split("$")[0];
```

NB This will get you all of the characters up to the `$`.  If you want that character too you will have to append it to this result.

Answer (score 11):

You can try this regex, it will replace the first occurance of `$` and everything after it with a `$`.

```
str.replace(/\$.*/, '$');
```

Input: `I have $100`
Output: `I have $`

Answer (score 7):

You need to get the substring and pass the index of the `$` as it's second parameter.

```
var newString = oldString.substring(0, oldString.indexOf("$", 0))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the subtring and indexOf methods like so:

```
var someString = "12345$67890";
alert(someString.substring(0, someString.indexOf('$')));
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/hNCHx/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.split()` to break it up at the dollar signs and then grab the first chunk:

```
var oldstring = "my epic string $ more stuff";
var split = oldstring.split("$");
var newstring = split[0] + "$";
alert(newstring); //outputs "my epic string $"
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are very helpful:

```
/([^$]*\$?)/.exec("aa$bc")[1] === "aa$"
```

Comment: Note: sort of fails if the string does not contain a $

Comment: This should be `/([^$]*\$?)/`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, actually the OP implies that there always is a `$` though.